# Write a recursive function that constructs a set

Tags: haskell, recursion, set

I'm having trouble with one of my hw problems.

> Write a recursive function that constructs a set
>   
> `mkSet :: Eq a => [a] −> Set a`

One of the hints given is I should be using another function called `isElement` to check each value for duplicates. Here is what I have for `isElement`

```
isElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isElement x [] = False
isElement x (y:xs) = if x == y then True else isElement x xs
```

One of the main errors I tend to get is everytime I call `isElement`, the value from `mkSet` returns as a Bool (which I am not sure how I am doing).

This is what I have for my `mkSet` currently (also keep in mind I'm just starting to learn Haskell)

```
mkSet :: Eq a => [a] -> Set a
mkSet x [] = isElement x (xs)
```

What is it that I should be doing?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `Set` defined?  Are you using the one from `Data.Set` (via `import Data.Set`) or is there a `data Set a = ...` somewhere in the code?

Comment: Try defining an `insert` function of type `Eq a => a -> Set a -> Set a` ; it would use `isElement` to decide what to do. Then see if you can define `mkSet` in terms of `insert`.

Comment: I suppose `Set a` is simply a synomym for a list `[a]` (i.e. you have `type Set = []` somewhere in the file; calling it set merely expresses that the list ought to contain no duplicates), but it would help if you made such a detail clear.

Comment: Note that `if x == y then True else isElement x xs` is more concisely written as `x == y || isElement x xs`. And if implementing `isElement` recursively isn't part of the problem requirements, it could be written as `isElement x xs = any (== x) xs`, or even as `isElement = elem`: that function exists in Prelude already.

Comment: it is not an error, but `x 'isElement' [] = ...` looks a bit nicer. For `mkSet` - you should take a list and just remain uniques in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think you ment `mkSet (x:xs)` instead of `mkSet x []`, because you use the xs.

Your function 'mkSet x [] = isElement x (xs)' is calling the function `isElement`, which in his place returns a `Bool`. So what you are assigning to `nkSet x []` is a `Bool` and no a `Set a`.

so what you do want is something like this:

```
mkSet' :: [a] -> [a]
mkSet' [] = []
mkSet' (x:[]) = [x]
mkSet' (x:xs) = if (isElement x xs) then (mkSet' xs) else (x:(mkSet' xs))
```

This function gives you a list with unique elements. The only thing you have to do know is to turn it into a set.